# async function gives me _40: 0, _65: 0, _55: null, _72: null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have an async function on Redux that needs to return a boolean to another Redux function after it finishes. However, when I print the output outside of the function, it always gives me this: `{"_40": 0, "_55": null, "_65": 0, "_72": null}`

I call the function from here:

```
const blocked = imBlocked(organizerId, userId);
console.log(blocked);
```

And the function itself is like this:

```
async function imBlocked(organizerId, userId) {
  const organizerSnapshot = await database().ref(`/users/${organizerId}`).once('value');
  const blockedList = (organizerSnapshot.val() && organizerSnapshot.val().blocked);
  let iBlocked = false;

  if (blockedList !== undefined && blockedList !== null) {
    for (let j = 0; j < blockedList.length; j += 1) {
      if (blockedList[j].user === userId) {
        iBlocked = true;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  if (iBlocked) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

I understand that, because it's an async function, it has to await for a promise to be completed. However, I struggle a bit with the sintax as well, since I can't rewrite the function like this:

```
imBlocked = async (organizerId, userId) => {}
```

because it throws me a `imBlocked is not defined` error.

Comment: `imBlocked = async (organizerId, userId) => {}` this is assigning something to an undefined variable, use `let` `const` or `var`
like `let imBlocked = async (organizerId, userId) => {}`

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you want to rewrite to an arrow function, assign the not defined variable using

```
const imBlocked async (organizerId, userId) => {}
```

Then I would get rid of the if Statement and, since it's a boolean, return the `iBlocked` variable directly.

Does this help?

```
const imBlocked async (organizerId, userId) => {
  const organizerSnapshot = await database().ref(`/users/${organizerId}`).once('value');
  const blockedList = (organizerSnapshot.val() && organizerSnapshot.val().blocked);
  let iBlocked = false;

  if (blockedList !== undefined && blockedList !== null) {
    for (let j = 0; j < blockedList.length; j += 1) {
      if (blockedList[j].user === userId) {
        iBlocked = true;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return iBlocked;
}
```